# ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable

Tags: ios, xcode, ld

How to solve the warning?

I have created a framework named "Designable" with a IBDesignable CustomView subclass of UIView with few IBInspectable properties, loadable from a Nib file in it.

In the main target of an app, I have set a view class to CustomView from Designable framework.
Everything works fine on a device or simulator but I get a warning when building the app.

Warning: "ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable"

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this!

Comment: @SteveBunting what is your configuration? I use xcodegen?

Comment: I don't use xcodegen. The issue is intermittent, sometimes it is fine and ocassionally not. But it appears that I get the error on every dependency when it happens. Like you, I also have an IBDesignable custom view. It will not display in storyboard, but displays the error 'Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): The agent crashed'. It works fine when running the app.